# GIT Clone from bare repo with remote URL

Tags: git, dvcs

We are trying out `GIT` to manage our repo.

To start off, we are 4 developers working under the same VPN connected.  We have a central server on which we have created a `bare` repo like this:

```
 git init --bare projectest.git
```

Later we are trying to clone the bare repo into one on my machine using the below command.

```
 git clone git://server/CeRepo/projectest.git/
```

where
**server** is our central machine where the bare repo is created
**CeRepo** is a Directory inside the **D: Drive** of Server
**projectest.git** is our empty bare repo.

When we run this from one of the developers machine

```
 git clone git://server/CeRepo/projectest.git/
```

I get this below error:

```
Cloning into 'projectest'...
fatal: unable to connect to **server**:
server[0: 192.168.13.221]: errno=No error
```

What can be the issue? Is it some thing related with ***GIT URL***

Comment: Default port for git protocol is 9418 - is that opened on the server? Also, have you checked this page: http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're talking about

> **CeRepo** is a Directory inside the **D: Drive** of Server

I assume, you're working on a Win32 machine and `CeRepo` is a shared folder on that box that contains the `projectest.git` directory.

Then, you'll access the share with

```
git clone //server/CeRepo/projectest.git
```

**Note:** there's no `git:` before the URL

---

For the sake of completeness: if your 4 users could access the administrative shares on `server`, you could also access the repo with the URL

```
//server/d$/CeRepo/projectest.git
```

assuming that the repo is located at

```
D:\CeRepo\projectest.git
```

Comment: perfect no git// needed.. any reasons please.. sorry new to GIT :D